# How can heat affect stored cables?

Tags: cable

I am considering moving my copious cables out into my shed. I live in a hot climate though (up to 46°C/113°F in summer). The shed is completely uninsulated, so it gets a lot hotter when in direct sun.

What I'm wondering is whether this intense heat will adversely affect my cables over time, even though they won't be in use. I'm talking all sorts of cables here: USB, Ethernet, HDMI, DVI, DP, etc.

Comment: It certainly could.  Plastic melts, heat on electronics is never good, most of those cables have circuitry in them.

Comment: I also lived for a few more years than I care to admit in a tropical country. Your bigger problem is not heat, is actually humidity, and more in the rain season. I would put them in a shoe box under the bed or some furniture at home.

Comment: The plastics used in cables won't melt at those temperatures, and electronics won't be permanently damaged if stored in those temperatures.  However, some plastics will degrade over time (plasticizers break down, leech out, etc.), so you may find that the plastic jackets become brittle, stiff, gooey, or otherwise not like new cables.  The warehouses the components and finished cables are stored in prior to sale often don't have great environments, but time there is limited.  If you are talking about long-term storage, you might find when you go to use them that you would prefer new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Most of those cables should have storage temperatures or operation temperatures on the packaging. If not a quick google search should help find them. From my physics classes I do know that heat effects metals and how they conduct electricity. Thermostats or thermal fuses are designed around this principle. The smaller gauge the wire the more the copper is effected by heat. As stated in the comments the plastics could melt in those conditions as well. I wouldn't advise that you store them in your shed but cables these days are pretty cheap and easily replaceable if anything happens. The chances of them starting a fire is extremely unlikely as well since most electrical cables are designed to melt away long before catching fire.

As @Loren Pechtel mentioned in the comment the insulation between the individual wires could melt and if they touch you will see some pretty strange errors in signal transmission due to the interference.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the metal.  Living in a climate where such temperatures are common my worry would be what happens to the insulation.

Comment: You're probably right. I will edit my answer